# Cactus plant identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

I received this cactus as a gift and I'd love to know the family/scientific name. Only one flower has bloomed since, it was between orange and yellow. At first it was perfectly spherical, but in one month it has become almost pear-shaped.

[image: Unknown cactus]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/86265/edit) your post to include an uploaded image. ——— Links are discouraged since 1) if they break they render this post and any answers worthless, and 2) they can be used to link to malicious websites. Thanks! 

Comment: Thank you tyersome, uploaded a new image!

Comment: You're welcome — that seems like an unusual shape for a cactus, but at least it's happy!  ——— You might find [this website](https://cactiguide.com/habitsearch/) helpful for figuring out your new friend's identity ...